# Why am I having a null point exception in this line ( status=employeeDAO.saveEmployee(emp);

Tags: spring, database

Why am I having a null point exception in this line `status=employeeDAO.saveEmployee(emp);`?

I am trying to use both bean as well as annotation in Spring with database.

```
public class Main {
    @Autowired
    static EmployeeDAO employeeDAO;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ac=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("config.xml");
        Employee emp=(Employee) ac.getBean("emp");
        emp.setId(2);
        emp.setName("praful");
        emp.setSalary(48000);

        //EmployeeDAO employeeDAO=(EmployeeDAO) ac.getBean("edao");

        int status=employeeDAO.saveEmployee(emp);  
        System.out.println(status);  

    }  
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<bean id="ds" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">  
<property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" />  
<property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database1" />  
<property name="username" value="root" />  
<property name="password" value="123456" />  
</bean>  

<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">  
<property name="dataSource" ref="ds"></property>  
</bean>  

<!--  
<bean id="edao" class="springWithDatabase.DAO.EmployeeDAO">  
<property name="jdbcTemplate" ref="jdbcTemplate"></property>  
</bean> 
-->   

<bean id="emp" class="springWithDatabase.Model.Employee">  

</bean>  

  <context:component-scan base-package="springWithDatabase"/>

</beans>
```

```
@Service
public class EmployeeDAO {
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;  

    public void setJdbcTemplate(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {  
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;  
    }  

    public int saveEmployee(Employee e){  
        String query="insert into employee values('"+e.getId()+"','"+e.getName()+"','"+e.getSalary()+"')";  
        return jdbcTemplate.update(query);  
    }  
    public int updateEmployee(Employee e){  
        String query="update employee set name='"+e.getName()+"',salary='"+e.getSalary()+"' where id='"+e.getId()+"' ";  
        return jdbcTemplate.update(query);  
    }  
    public int deleteEmployee(Employee e){  
        String query="delete from employee where id='"+e.getId()+"' ";  
        return jdbcTemplate.update(query);  
    }  
}
```

```
public class Employee {
    private int id;  
    private String name;  
    private float salary;
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public float getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }
    public void setSalary(float salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }  
}
```

Comment: Can you share the full stacktrace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Main class is not declared as a bean therefore he is not managed by Spring container so you cannot inject dependencies in it.

Use `ac.getBean("edao")` to get your EmployeeDAO bean from your main method